# react-children expect to receive a single react element child error

Tags: react-redux

I was trying to create a survey app using React, Redux. While trying to run the program on `localhost:3000`, I am getting this `React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child` error. I have tried using various solutions which programmers have mentioned elsewhere but nothing has worked. The codes are as below. I must admit I am an absolute tyro as far as programming is concerned

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter,Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Header';


const Dashboard =() => <h2>Dashboard</h2>;
const SurveyNew =() => <h2>SurveyNew</h2>;
const Landing =() => <h2>Landing</h2>;

const App = () => {
 return (
 <div>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Route exact path= "/" component = {Landing} />
      <Route exact path = "/surveys" component= {Dashboard} />
      <Route path = "/surveys/new" component={SurveyNew} />
    </div> 
  </BrowserRouter>
 </div>
 );

};

export default App;
```

The code of header.js file is as below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class Header extends Component {

 render () {
 return (
  <div>
   <nav>
    <div className = "nav-wrapper">
      <a className = "left brand-logo">
      Emaily
      </a>
       <ul className="right">
        <li>
         <a> Login with Google </a>
        </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </div>
 );
}

}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Try placing your `<Header />` outside the `BrowserRouter` component.

Comment: Hi! tried that but doesn't work. Can you pls give illustrate the point using my code. As mentioned earlier, i am very new to programming and using a tutorial to learn